# Google Spreadsheet - Write to Blank Worksheet

Tags: c#, google-docs-api

I'm creating a new worksheet in a Google Spreadsheet using the C# library.  After creating the worksheet, I want to write to it.  I don't have a LocalName, since it's a new sheet with no header.  Has anybody done this before?

```
newRow.Elements.Add(new ListEntry.Custom
{
    Value = value,
    LocalName = local
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For new worksheet, I would suggest using the Cell based feed to add the first row:
  https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#changing_contents_of_a_cell

Simply use the indexes A1 to A{N} to add the header and continue using the list based feed as you used to.